# How to make navbar dynamically responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css

To make sure that the title doesn't confuse anyone, here is my question. I was asked whether it was possible to make navbar dynamically responsive. What I mean by that is that for different width of the screen different amount of links will be shown and the ones hidden will be inside the more dropdown element which will appear as the other elements are hidden. To clarify, if we have 9 links on maximum width, on a lets say 100px(not exactly for every 100px but just to give an idea) less width we will have 7 with 8th and 9th links inside the more dropdown. which will appear instead of them. Never thought I would run into such request and they specified that they wanted it to be done with vanilla Javascript. Honestly this is interesting but a bit odd request I guess, so don't really have a clue what to even call such navbar, hence the name.

Comment: yes, it is possible...

Comment: Can you provide an example? I think that this idea can be done with CSS.

Comment: @luknij can you provide an example?

Comment: I think I found what you need: https://css-tricks.com/the-priority-navigation-pattern/ It requires JavaScript after all...

Comment: Or even this one: https://codepen.io/lukejacksonn/pen/BowbWE

Comment: @Unix this looks amazing, I think this might be what might be usefull